# How to allow an argument AND no argument and act differently on them with getopts

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to have getopts setup for my script in such a way that it accepts no argument (`-p`) but so that it can also accept an argument (`-p library`). Both need to be accepted. They're (argument and no argument) are both allowed. The argument should be allowed to be any string. See below:

```
while getopts "p:sdih" opt; do
                case ${opt} in
                        p )
                                #WHEN NO ARGUMENT IS GIVEN, DO THIS

                                selection="plex"

                                #WHEN AN ARGUMENT IS GIVEN, DO THIS

                                selection="plex"
                                argument=true
                                optarg="$OPTARG"
                                ;;

                        s )
                                selection="sonarr"
                                ;;

                        d )
                                selection="deluge"
                                ;;
                        i )
                                selection="info"
                                ;;

                        h )
                                usage | column -t -s "|"
                                exit
                                ;;
                        \? )
                                echo "Invalid option"
                                usage | column -t -s "|"
                                exit
                                ;;
                esac
        done 2>/dev/null
        shift $((OPTIND -1))
```

That's how it needs to work. But I'm new to getopts so I don't know how to do this yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for missing arguments, start *optstring* with a colon `:` by changing `"p:sdih"` to `":p:sdih"`

Then, add a case argument before `\?)` like so:

```
:) echo "Option $OPTARG has no argument."
   exit
   ;;
```

You can check for more than one option by evaluating `"$OPTARG"`

> If an option-argument is missing:
>
> - If the first character of optstring is a *colon*, the shell    variable specified by name shall be set to the     character
>   and the shell variable OPTARG shall be set to the    option character
>   found.
> - Otherwise, the shell variable specified by name shall be set    to the *question-mark* character, the shell variable OPTARG    shall be
>   unset, and a diagnostic message shall be written to    standard error.
>   This condition shall be considered to be an    error detected in the
>   way arguments were presented to the    invoking application, but shall
>   not be an error in getopts    processing; a diagnostic message shall
>   be written as stated,    but the exit status shall be zero.

More information can be found [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopts.1p.html)